# Как принять любые данные от пользователя и проанализировать их?

Tags: c++

Если запрашиваю данные от пользователя `(std::cin)`, то данные преобразовываются к определенному типу. Пробовал установить тип `auto` для входных данных, но компилятор такое не принимает. Как получить любые данные от пользователя, самому определить их тип и, в зависимости от типа данных, выдать сообщение о несоответствии требованиям для этих данных?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int users_num;
    cin >> users_num;
    cout << users_num;
    return 0;
}
```

Получаю следующий вывод если ввожу строку:

```
Enter an integer: werwer
0
```

Или такой, если ввожу дробное:

```
Enter an integer: 3245.2345
3245
```

Правильно ли будет принимать ввод как строку (std::string) и разбирать ее с помощью регулярок? Я заметил, что 45.45 в строке преобразовывается в 45,45. На что еще нужно обратить внимание?

Comment: Вводите строку, и сами ее анализируйте...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, это логично. А как получить весь ввод до нажатия Enter? Сейчас остается только первое слово (набор символов до пробела).

Comment: [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

Comment: @avp, спасибо, изучу.